# PPP connection created by SonicWall NetExtender on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: ubuntu, linux-networking, sonicwall

I'm trying to connect to the client VPN via Sonicwall NetExtender. On Windows there is no problem, but I cant't connect on my Linux Desktop (sometimes it works, but it's the exception).

When I connect everything seems to be ok, but the result is as if it's not connected. If I do a `ip a` on the console I can see the `ppp0` connection created,

```
20: ppp0: <POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1280 qdisc fq_codel state UNKNOWN group default qlen 3
    link/ppp 
    inet 192.168.200.200 peer 192.0.2.1/32 scope global ppp0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Can I assume the problem is related to that `192.0.2.1/32`? The provider IP is not that, but may be its local addreess.
If it's so, how can I change the `ipcp-accept-remote` flag of the ppp connection created by the NetExtender client? Can I even change it after the connection is created?

**Edit 19/07/21**:

I've tried disabling NetworkManager with no effect. Then I've enabled debug logging of NM and got this:

```
Jul 19 21:01:16 this-machine NetworkManager[11584]: <debug> [1626724876.5423] device[62bc60a802291a89] (enp2s0): activation-stage: schedule activate_stage5_ip_config_result_6,v6 (id 317)
Jul 19 21:01:16 this-machine NetworkManager[11584]: <debug> [1626724876.5424] device[62bc60a802291a89] (enp2s0): activation-stage: invoke activate_stage5_ip_config_result_6,v6 (id 317)
Jul 19 21:01:16 this-machine NetworkManager[11584]: <debug> [1626724876.5425] device[62bc60a802291a89] (enp2s0): ip6-config: update (commit=1, new-config=0x55a82e7432b0)
Jul 19 21:01:16 this-machine NetworkManager[11584]: <debug> [1626724876.5426] platform: (enp2s0) address: adding or updating IPv6 address: fe80::d097:1a59:8045:859a/64 lft forever pref forever lifetime 24-0[4294967295,4294967295] dev 2 flags permanent,noprefixroute src unknown
Jul 19 21:01:16 this-machine NetworkManager[11584]: <debug> [1626724876.5431] platform-linux: do-add-ip6-address[2: fe80::d097:1a59:8045:859a]: success
Jul 19 21:01:17 this-machine NetworkManager[11584]: <debug> [1626724877.9237] ndisc-lndp[0x55a82e6c2720,"enp2s0"]: processing libndp events
Jul 19 21:01:17 this-machine NetworkManager[11584]: <debug> [1626724877.9238] ndisc-lndp[0x55a82e6c2720,"enp2s0"]: received router advertisement at 26
Jul 19 21:01:17 this-machine NetworkManager[11584]: <debug> [1626724877.9239] ndisc[0x55a82e6c2720,"enp2s0"]: scheduling next now/lifetime check: 28 seconds
Jul 19 21:01:17 this-machine NetworkManager[11584]: <debug> [1626724877.9239] ndisc-lndp[0x55a82e6c2720,"enp2s0"]: received router advertisement at 26
Jul 19 21:01:17 this-machine NetworkManager[11584]: <debug> [1626724877.9239] ndisc[0x55a82e6c2720,"enp2s0"]: scheduling next now/lifetime check: 28 seconds
Jul 19 21:01:21 this-machine NetworkManager[11584]: <debug> [1626724881.8714] platform: (ppp0) signal: link   added: 12: ppp0 <NOARP,DOWN;pointopoint,multicast,noarp> mtu 1500 arp 512 ppp* not-init addrgenmode eui64 driver ppp rx:0,0 tx:0,0
Jul 19 21:01:21 this-machine NetworkManager[11584]: <debug> [1626724881.8716] device[ec7347458b1bec22] (ppp0): constructed (NMDevicePpp)
Jul 19 21:01:21 this-machine NetworkManager[11584]: <debug> [1626724881.8716] device[ec7347458b1bec22] (ppp0): start setup of NMDevicePpp, kernel ifindex 12
Jul 19 21:01:21 this-machine NetworkManager[11584]: <debug> [1626724881.8718] platform-linux: error reading net:/sys/class/net/ppp0/phys_port_id: error reading 4096 bytes from file descriptor: La operación no está soportada
Jul 19 21:01:21 this-machine NetworkManager[11584]: <debug> [1626724881.8719] platform-linux: sysctl: reading 'net:/sys/class/net/ppp0/dev_id': '0x0'
Jul 19 21:01:21 this-machine NetworkManager[11584]: <debug> [1626724881.8720] platform-linux: error reading net:/sys/class/net/ppp0/device/sriov_totalvfs: Failed to open file "device/sriov_totalvfs" with openat: No existe el archivo o el directorio
Jul 19 21:01:21 this-machine NetworkManager[11584]: <debug> [1626724881.8721] device[ec7347458b1bec22] (ppp0): unmanaged: flags set to [platform-init,external-down=0x810/0x810/unmanaged/unrealized], set-unmanaged [external-down=0x800])
Jul 19 21:01:21 this-machine NetworkManager[11584]: <debug> [1626724881.8721] device[ec7347458b1bec22] (ppp0): unmanaged: flags set to [platform-init,external-down,!by-type=0x810/0x818/unmanaged/unrealized], set-managed [by-type=0x8])
Jul 19 21:01:21 this-machine NetworkManager[11584]: <debug> [1626724881.8722] device[ec7347458b1bec22] (ppp0): unmanaged: flags set to [platform-init,external-down,!sleeping,!by-type=0x810/0x819/unmanaged/unrealized], set-managed [sleeping=0x1])
Jul 19 21:01:21 this-machine NetworkManager[11584]: <info>  [1626724881.8729] manager: (ppp0): new Ppp device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/4)
Jul 19 21:01:21 this-machine NetworkManager[11584]: <debug> [1626724881.8932] platform-linux: UDEV event: action 'add' subsys 'net' device 'ppp0' (12); seqnum=9829
Jul 19 21:01:21 this-machine NetworkManager[11584]: <debug> [1626724881.8940] platform: (ppp0) signal: link changed: 12: ppp0 <NOARP,DOWN;pointopoint,multicast,noarp> mtu 1500 arp 512 ppp* init addrgenmode eui64 driver ppp rx:0,0 tx:0,0
Jul 19 21:01:21 this-machine NetworkManager[11584]: <debug> [1626724881.8940] device[ec7347458b1bec22] (ppp0): queued link change for ifindex 12
Jul 19 21:01:21 this-machine NetworkManager[11584]: <debug> [1626724881.8944] device[ec7347458b1bec22] (ppp0): unmanaged: flags set to [platform-init,external-down,!sleeping,!by-type,!user-settings=0x810/0x859/unmanaged], set-managed [user-settings=0x40])
Jul 19 21:01:21 this-machine NetworkManager[11584]: <debug> [1626724881.8945] device[ec7347458b1bec22] (ppp0): unmanaged: flags set to [external-down,!sleeping,!by-type,!platform-init,!user-settings=0x800/0x859/manageable], set-managed [platform-init=0x10], reason managed)
Jul 19 21:01:21 this-machine NetworkManager[11584]: <debug> [1626724881.8945] device[ec7347458b1bec22] (ppp0): ip4-config: update (commit=0, new-config=0x55a82e6c2d50)
Jul 19 21:01:21 this-machine NetworkManager[11584]: <debug> [1626724881.8948] device[ec7347458b1bec22] (ppp0): ip4-config: set IP Config instance (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/IP4Config/4)
Jul 19 21:01:21 this-machine NetworkManager[11584]: <debug> [1626724881.8950] dns-mgr: (device_ip_config_changed): queueing DNS updates (1)
Jul 19 21:01:21 this-machine NetworkManager[11584]: <debug> [1626724881.8950] dns-mgr: (device_ip_config_changed): DNS configuration did not change
Jul 19 21:01:21 this-machine NetworkManager[11584]: <debug> [1626724881.8950] dns-mgr: (device_ip_config_changed): no DNS changes to commit (0)
Jul 19 21:01:21 this-machine NetworkManager[11584]: <debug> [1626724881.8952] platform-linux: sysctl: reading '/proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/ppp0/disable_ipv6': '0'
Jul 19 21:01:21 this-machine NetworkManager[11584]: <debug> [1626724881.8952] device[ec7347458b1bec22] (ppp0): ip6-config: update (commit=0, new-config=0x55a82e6a87d0)
Jul 19 21:01:21 this-machine NetworkManager[11584]: <debug> [1626724881.8955] device[ec7347458b1bec22] (ppp0): ip6-config: set IP Config instance (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/IP6Config/4)
Jul 19 21:01:21 this-machine NetworkManager[11584]: <debug> [1626724881.8957] dns-mgr: (device_ip_config_changed): queueing DNS updates (1)
Jul 19 21:01:21 this-machine NetworkManager[11584]: <debug> [1626724881.8957] dns-mgr: (device_ip_config_changed): DNS configuration did not change
Jul 19 21:01:21 this-machine NetworkManager[11584]: <debug> [1626724881.8957] dns-mgr: (device_ip_config_changed): no DNS changes to commit (0)
Jul 19 21:01:21 this-machine NetworkManager[11584]: <debug> [1626724881.9377] platform: (ppp0) signal: link changed: 12: ppp0 <NOARP,DOWN;pointopoint,multicast,noarp> mtu 1280 arp 512 ppp* init addrgenmode eui64 driver ppp rx:0,0 tx:0,0
Jul 19 21:01:21 this-machine NetworkManager[11584]: <debug> [1626724881.9378] device[ec7347458b1bec22] (ppp0): queued link change for ifindex 12
Jul 19 21:01:21 this-machine NetworkManager[11584]: <debug> [1626724881.9652] platform: (ppp0) signal: address 4   added: X.X.X.X/32 lft forever pref forever lifetime 30-0[4294967295,4294967295] dev 12 flags permanent src kernel
Jul 19 21:01:21 this-machine NetworkManager[11584]: <debug> [1626724881.9653] device[ec7347458b1bec22] (ppp0): queued IP4 config change
Jul 19 21:01:21 this-machine NetworkManager[11584]: <debug> [1626724881.9654] device[ec7347458b1bec22] (ppp0): ip4-config: update (commit=0, new-config=0x55a82e6c2c20)
Jul 19 21:01:21 this-machine NetworkManager[11584]: <debug> [1626724881.9661] device[ec7347458b1bec22] (ppp0): ip4-config: update IP Config instance (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/IP4Config/4)
Jul 19 21:01:21 this-machine NetworkManager[11584]: <debug> [1626724881.9665] dns-mgr: (device_ip_config_changed): queueing DNS updates (1)
Jul 19 21:01:21 this-machine NetworkManager[11584]: <debug> [1626724881.9665] dns-mgr: (device_ip_config_changed): DNS configuration did not change
Jul 19 21:01:21 this-machine NetworkManager[11584]: <debug> [1626724881.9666] dns-mgr: (device_ip_config_changed): no DNS changes to commit (0)
Jul 19 21:01:21 this-machine NetworkManager[11584]: <debug> [1626724881.9667] platform: (ppp0) signal: address 4 removed: X.X.X.X/32 lft forever pref forever lifetime 30-0[4294967295,4294967295] dev 12 flags permanent src kernel
Jul 19 21:01:21 this-machine NetworkManager[11584]: <debug> [1626724881.9668] device[ec7347458b1bec22] (ppp0): queued IP4 config change
Jul 19 21:01:21 this-machine NetworkManager[11584]: <debug> [1626724881.9720] platform: (ppp0) signal: address 4   added: X.X.X.X/32 lft forever pref forever lifetime 30-0[4294967295,4294967295] ptp X.X.X.X dev 12 flags permanent src kernel
Jul 19 21:01:21 this-machine NetworkManager[11584]: <debug> [1626724881.9722] device[ec7347458b1bec22] (ppp0): ip4-config: update (commit=0, new-config=0x55a82e6c2c20)
Jul 19 21:01:21 this-machine NetworkManager[11584]: <debug> [1626724881.9725] device[ec7347458b1bec22] (ppp0): ip4-config: update IP Config instance (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/IP4Config/4)
Jul 19 21:01:21 this-machine NetworkManager[11584]: <debug> [1626724881.9725] dns-mgr: (device_ip_config_changed): queueing DNS updates (1)
Jul 19 21:01:21 this-machine NetworkManager[11584]: <debug> [1626724881.9725] dns-mgr: (device_ip_config_changed): DNS configuration did not change
Jul 19 21:01:21 this-machine NetworkManager[11584]: <debug> [1626724881.9725] dns-mgr: (device_ip_config_changed): no DNS changes to commit (0)
Jul 19 21:01:21 this-machine NetworkManager[11584]: <debug> [1626724881.9743] platform: (ppp0) signal: link changed: 12: ppp0 <NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP;pointopoint,multicast,noarp,up,running,lowerup> mtu 1280 arp 512 ppp* init addrgenmode eui64 driver ppp rx:5,58 tx:4,40
Jul 19 21:01:21 this-machine NetworkManager[11584]: <debug> [1626724881.9744] device[ec7347458b1bec22] (ppp0): queued link change for ifindex 12
Jul 19 21:01:21 this-machine NetworkManager[11584]: <debug> [1626724881.9746] device[ec7347458b1bec22] (ppp0): unmanaged: flags set to [!sleeping,!by-type,!platform-init,!user-settings,!external-down=0x0/0x859/managed], set-managed [external-down=0x800], reason connection-assumed, transition-state)
Jul 19 21:01:21 this-machine NetworkManager[11584]: <info>  [1626724881.9747] device (ppp0): state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'connection-assumed', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Jul 19 21:01:21 this-machine NetworkManager[11584]: <debug> [1626724881.9747] device[ec7347458b1bec22] (ppp0): add_pending_action (1): 'in-state-change'
Jul 19 21:01:21 this-machine NetworkManager[11584]: <debug> [1626724881.9748] platform-linux: sysctl: reading '/proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/ppp0/accept_ra': '1'
Jul 19 21:01:21 this-machine NetworkManager[11584]: <debug> [1626724881.9748] platform-linux: sysctl: reading '/proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/ppp0/forwarding': '0'
Jul 19 21:01:21 this-machine NetworkManager[11584]: <debug> [1626724881.9749] platform-linux: sysctl: reading '/proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/ppp0/hop_limit': '64'
Jul 19 21:01:21 this-machine NetworkManager[11584]: <debug> [1626724881.9749] platform-linux: sysctl: reading '/proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/ppp0/use_tempaddr': '2'
Jul 19 21:01:21 this-machine NetworkManager[11584]: <debug> [1626724881.9754] device[ec7347458b1bec22] (ppp0): add_pending_action (2): 'recheck-available'
Jul 19 21:01:21 this-machine NetworkManager[11584]: <debug> [1626724881.9761] device[ec7347458b1bec22] (ppp0): connectivity state changed from UNKNOWN to NONE
Jul 19 21:01:21 this-machine NetworkManager[11584]: <debug> [1626724881.9762] device[ec7347458b1bec22] (ppp0): connectivity state changed from UNKNOWN to NONE
Jul 19 21:01:21 this-machine NetworkManager[11584]: <debug> [1626724881.9763] device[ec7347458b1bec22] (ppp0): remove_pending_action (1): 'in-state-change'
Jul 19 21:01:21 this-machine NetworkManager[11584]: <debug> [1626724881.9769] platform: (ppp0) signal: route   4   added: X.X.X.X/32 via 0.0.0.0 dev 12 metric 0 mss 0 rt-src rt-kernel scope link pref-src X.X.X.X
Jul 19 21:01:21 this-machine NetworkManager[11584]: <debug> [1626724881.9769] device[ec7347458b1bec22] (ppp0): queued IP4 config change
Jul 19 21:01:21 this-machine NetworkManager[11584]: <debug> [1626724881.9770] device[ec7347458b1bec22] (ppp0): add_pending_action (2): 'queued-state-change-disconnected'
Jul 19 21:01:21 this-machine NetworkManager[11584]: <debug> [1626724881.9770] device[ec7347458b1bec22] (ppp0): queue-state[disconnected, reason:none, id:336]: queue state change
Jul 19 21:01:21 this-machine NetworkManager[11584]: <debug> [1626724881.9770] device[ec7347458b1bec22] (ppp0): is available, will transition to disconnected
Jul 19 21:01:21 this-machine NetworkManager[11584]: <debug> [1626724881.9770] device[ec7347458b1bec22] (ppp0): remove_pending_action (1): 'recheck-available'
Jul 19 21:01:21 this-machine NetworkManager[11584]: <debug> [1626724881.9771] device[ec7347458b1bec22] (ppp0): queue-state[disconnected, reason:none, id:336]: change state
Jul 19 21:01:21 this-machine NetworkManager[11584]: <info>  [1626724881.9772] device (ppp0): state change: unavailable -> disconnected (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Jul 19 21:01:21 this-machine NetworkManager[11584]: <debug> [1626724881.9772] device[ec7347458b1bec22] (ppp0): add_pending_action (2): 'in-state-change'
Jul 19 21:01:21 this-machine NetworkManager[11584]: <debug> [1626724881.9782] device[ec7347458b1bec22] (ppp0): add_pending_action (3): 'autoactivate'
Jul 19 21:01:21 this-machine NetworkManager[11584]: <debug> [1626724881.9782] device[ec7347458b1bec22] (ppp0): remove_pending_action (2): 'in-state-change'
Jul 19 21:01:21 this-machine NetworkManager[11584]: <debug> [1626724881.9783] device[ec7347458b1bec22] (ppp0): remove_pending_action (1): 'queued-state-change-disconnected'
Jul 19 21:01:21 this-machine NetworkManager[11584]: <debug> [1626724881.9783] device[ec7347458b1bec22] (ppp0): ip4-config: update (commit=0, new-config=0x55a82e6c2c20)
Jul 19 21:01:21 this-machine NetworkManager[11584]: <debug> [1626724881.9785] device[ec7347458b1bec22] (ppp0): ip4-config: update IP Config instance (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/IP4Config/4)
Jul 19 21:01:21 this-machine NetworkManager[11584]: <debug> [1626724881.9785] dns-mgr: (device_ip_config_changed): queueing DNS updates (1)
Jul 19 21:01:21 this-machine NetworkManager[11584]: <debug> [1626724881.9786] dns-mgr: (device_ip_config_changed): DNS configuration did not change
Jul 19 21:01:21 this-machine NetworkManager[11584]: <debug> [1626724881.9786] dns-mgr: (device_ip_config_changed): no DNS changes to commit (0)
Jul 19 21:01:21 this-machine NetworkManager[11584]: <debug> [1626724881.9787] device[ec7347458b1bec22] (ppp0): remove_pending_action (0): 'autoactivate'
Jul 19 21:01:22 this-machine NetworkManager[11584]: <debug> [1626724882.7277] ndisc-lndp[0x55a82e6c2720,"enp2s0"]: processing libndp events
Jul 19 21:01:22 this-machine NetworkManager[11584]: <debug> [1626724882.7279] ndisc-lndp[0x55a82e6c2720,"enp2s0"]: received router advertisement at 30
Jul 19 21:01:22 this-machine NetworkManager[11584]: <debug> [1626724882.7279] ndisc[0x55a82e6c2720,"enp2s0"]: scheduling next now/lifetime check: 24 seconds
Jul 19 21:01:22 this-machine NetworkManager[11584]: <debug> [1626724882.7279] ndisc-lndp[0x55a82e6c2720,"enp2s0"]: received router advertisement at 30
Jul 19 21:01:22 this-machine NetworkManager[11584]: <debug> [1626724882.7280] ndisc[0x55a82e6c2720,"enp2s0"]: scheduling next now/lifetime check: 24 seconds
Jul 19 21:01:23 this-machine NetworkManager[11584]: <debug> [1626724883.0049] ndisc-lndp[0x55a82e6c2720,"enp2s0"]: processing libndp events
Jul 19 21:01:23 this-machine NetworkManager[11584]: <debug> [1626724883.0275] platform: (enp2s0) signal: route   4   added: Y.Y.Y.Y/32 via 192.168.1.1 dev 2 metric 0 mss 0 rt-src rt-boot scope global
Jul 19 21:01:23 this-machine NetworkManager[11584]: <debug> [1626724883.0276] device[62bc60a802291a89] (enp2s0): queued IP4 config change
Jul 19 21:01:23 this-machine NetworkManager[11584]: <debug> [1626724883.0277] device[62bc60a802291a89] (enp2s0): ip4-config: update (commit=0, new-config=0x55a82e6c2c20)
Jul 19 21:01:23 this-machine NetworkManager[11584]: <debug> [1626724883.0283] device[62bc60a802291a89] (enp2s0): ip4-config: update IP Config instance (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/IP4Config/2)
Jul 19 21:01:23 this-machine NetworkManager[11584]: <debug> [1626724883.0284] dns-mgr: (device_ip_config_changed): queueing DNS updates (1)
Jul 19 21:01:23 this-machine NetworkManager[11584]: <debug> [1626724883.0284] dns-mgr: (device_ip_config_changed): DNS configuration did not change
Jul 19 21:01:23 this-machine NetworkManager[11584]: <debug> [1626724883.0285] dns-mgr: (device_ip_config_changed): no DNS changes to commit (0)
Jul 19 21:01:23 this-machine NetworkManager[11584]: <debug> [1626724883.0300] platform: (enp2s0) signal: route   4   added: 192.168.1.1/32 via 0.0.0.0 dev 2 metric 0 mss 0 rt-src rt-boot scope link
Jul 19 21:01:23 this-machine NetworkManager[11584]: <debug> [1626724883.0302] device[62bc60a802291a89] (enp2s0): queued IP4 config change
Jul 19 21:01:23 this-machine NetworkManager[11584]: <debug> [1626724883.0303] device[62bc60a802291a89] (enp2s0): ip4-config: update (commit=0, new-config=0x55a82e6c2c20)
Jul 19 21:01:23 this-machine NetworkManager[11584]: <debug> [1626724883.0308] device[62bc60a802291a89] (enp2s0): ip4-config: update IP Config instance (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/IP4Config/2)
Jul 19 21:01:23 this-machine NetworkManager[11584]: <debug> [1626724883.0309] dns-mgr: (device_ip_config_changed): queueing DNS updates (1)
Jul 19 21:01:23 this-machine NetworkManager[11584]: <debug> [1626724883.0309] dns-mgr: (device_ip_config_changed): DNS configuration did not change
Jul 19 21:01:23 this-machine NetworkManager[11584]: <debug> [1626724883.0309] dns-mgr: (device_ip_config_changed): no DNS changes to commit (0)
Jul 19 21:01:23 this-machine NetworkManager[11584]: <debug> [1626724883.0363] platform: (ppp0) signal: route   4   added: X.X.X.X/24 via X.X.X.X dev 12 metric 0 mss 0 rt-src rt-boot scope link
Jul 19 21:01:23 this-machine NetworkManager[11584]: <debug> [1626724883.0364] device[ec7347458b1bec22] (ppp0): queued IP4 config change
Jul 19 21:01:23 this-machine NetworkManager[11584]: <debug> [1626724883.0365] device[ec7347458b1bec22] (ppp0): ip4-config: update (commit=0, new-config=0x55a82e6c2c20)
Jul 19 21:01:23 this-machine NetworkManager[11584]: <debug> [1626724883.0367] device[ec7347458b1bec22] (ppp0): ip4-config: update IP Config instance (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/IP4Config/4)
Jul 19 21:01:23 this-machine NetworkManager[11584]: <debug> [1626724883.0368] dns-mgr: (device_ip_config_changed): queueing DNS updates (1)
Jul 19 21:01:23 this-machine NetworkManager[11584]: <debug> [1626724883.0368] dns-mgr: (device_ip_config_changed): DNS configuration did not change
Jul 19 21:01:23 this-machine NetworkManager[11584]: <debug> [1626724883.0368] dns-mgr: (device_ip_config_changed): no DNS changes to commit (0)
Jul 19 21:01:23 this-machine NetworkManager[11584]: <debug> [1626724883.0380] platform: (ppp0) signal: route   4   added: X.X.X.0/24 via X.X.X.X dev 12 metric 0 mss 0 rt-src rt-boot scope link
Jul 19 21:01:23 this-machine NetworkManager[11584]: <debug> [1626724883.0382] device[ec7347458b1bec22] (ppp0): queued IP4 config change
Jul 19 21:01:23 this-machine NetworkManager[11584]: <debug> [1626724883.0383] device[ec7347458b1bec22] (ppp0): ip4-config: update (commit=0, new-config=0x55a82e6c2c20)
Jul 19 21:01:23 this-machine NetworkManager[11584]: <debug> [1626724883.0386] device[ec7347458b1bec22] (ppp0): ip4-config: update IP Config instance (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/IP4Config/4)
Jul 19 21:01:23 this-machine NetworkManager[11584]: <debug> [1626724883.0387] dns-mgr: (device_ip_config_changed): queueing DNS updates (1)
Jul 19 21:01:23 this-machine NetworkManager[11584]: <debug> [1626724883.0387] dns-mgr: (device_ip_config_changed): DNS configuration did not change
Jul 19 21:01:23 this-machine NetworkManager[11584]: <debug> [1626724883.0387] dns-mgr: (device_ip_config_changed): no DNS changes to commit (0)
Jul 19 21:01:25 this-machine NetworkManager[11584]: <debug> [1626724885.3739] ndisc-lndp[0x55a82e6c2720,"enp2s0"]: processing libndp events
Jul 19 21:01:25 this-machine NetworkManager[11584]: <debug> [1626724885.3740] ndisc-lndp[0x55a82e6c2720,"enp2s0"]: received router advertisement at 33
Jul 19 21:01:25 this-machine NetworkManager[11584]: <debug> [1626724885.3741] ndisc[0x55a82e6c2720,"enp2s0"]: scheduling next now/lifetime check: 30 seconds
Jul 19 21:01:25 this-machine NetworkManager[11584]: <debug> [1626724885.3741] ndisc[0x55a82e6c2720,"enp2s0"]: neighbor discovery configuration changed [G]:
Jul 19 21:01:25 this-machine NetworkManager[11584]: <debug> [1626724885.3743] ndisc[0x55a82e6c2720,"enp2s0"]:   dhcp-level managed
Jul 19 21:01:25 this-machine NetworkManager[11584]: <debug> [1626724885.3744] ndisc[0x55a82e6c2720,"enp2s0"]:   hop limit      : 64
Jul 19 21:01:25 this-machine NetworkManager[11584]: <debug> [1626724885.3744] ndisc[0x55a82e6c2720,"enp2s0"]:   gateway fe80::ee08:6bff:fe5c:738c pref low exp 29,5406
Jul 19 21:01:25 this-machine NetworkManager[11584]: <debug> [1626724885.3745] device[62bc60a802291a89] (enp2s0): activation-stage: schedule activate_stage5_ip_config_result_6,v6 (id 348)
Jul 19 21:01:25 this-machine NetworkManager[11584]: <debug> [1626724885.3746] device[62bc60a802291a89] (enp2s0): activation-stage: invoke activate_stage5_ip_config_result_6,v6 (id 348)
Jul 19 21:01:25 this-machine NetworkManager[11584]: <debug> [1626724885.3747] device[62bc60a802291a89] (enp2s0): ip6-config: update (commit=1, new-config=0x55a82e7434d0)
Jul 19 21:01:25 this-machine NetworkManager[11584]: <debug> [1626724885.3748] platform: (enp2s0) address: adding or updating IPv6 address: fe80::d097:1a59:8045:859a/64 lft forever pref forever lifetime 33-0[4294967295,4294967295] dev 2 flags permanent,noprefixroute src unknown
Jul 19 21:01:25 this-machine NetworkManager[11584]: <debug> [1626724885.3752] platform-linux: do-add-ip6-address[2: fe80::d097:1a59:8045:859a]: success
Jul 19 21:01:28 this-machine NetworkManager[11584]: <debug> [1626724888.0721] ndisc-lndp[0x55a82e6c2720,"enp2s0"]: processing libndp events
```

Come to my attention the following lines:

```
Jul 19 21:01:21 this-machine NetworkManager[11584]: <debug> [1626724881.8718] platform-linux: error reading net:/sys/class/net/ppp0/phys_port_id: error reading 4096 bytes from file descriptor: La operación no está soportada
Jul 19 21:01:21 this-machine NetworkManager[11584]: <debug> [1626724881.8720] platform-linux: error reading net:/sys/class/net/ppp0/device/sriov_totalvfs: Failed to open file "device/sriov_totalvfs" with openat: No existe el archivo o el directorio
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: PPPD is in my mind usually not a VPN .-) and i belive you setup your VPN Worngly, as i belive that 192.0.2.1 is not owned by you and is imho not reserved for LAN usage. change or update it to 192.168 or 172.16 or 10.

Comment: I've tryed some remotes with `ifconfig ppp0 pointopoint XXX.XXX.2.1` and even the public IP of the provider and I'm still with no network connectivity. May the change require some other configuration? Unfortunately I have no access to a configuration file of the created ppp cause it's configured dinamicly by the NetExtender client. Nevertheless, I'll try to ask some coworkers about the real IP I need. Thanks.

Comment: I've verified the original IP with a working Windows client.